# Find all parameters for for which the series is convergent - checking

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm not sure if my reasoning is good. Find all parameters $a$ for for which the series is convergent $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{w_n}$ where $\displaystyle  w_n=(\sqrt[n]{2}-1)^{(-1)}$

My try: First I show that $\displaystyle n< w_n$ it's equivalent to $n(\sqrt[n]{2}-1)<1$ but as $n$ goes to infinity we have $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}n(\sqrt[n]{2}-1)=\ln{2}<1$ so for sufficient large $n$ the inequality holds (here I'm not sure if it's legal to show this ineq)

next taking $|a| < 1$ and from our inequality we have $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{w_n} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^n$ since $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^n$ is here geometric series so it converge hence $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{w_n}$ must converge too. For $|a|\ge 1$ we show analogically that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{w_n}$ diverge.

Is it proper thinkng?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking your reasoning for $a > 0$, it is correct that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}n(\sqrt[n]{2}-1)=\ln{2}<1.$

Hence, for sufficiently large $n$,

$$(\sqrt[n]{2}-1)<n^{-1} \implies n < (\sqrt[n]{2}-1)^{-1}.$$

If $0 < a < 1$, we have $\ln a < 0$, and

$$n \ln a > (\sqrt[n]{2}-1)^{-1} \ln a \implies a^{(\sqrt[n]{2}-1)^{-1}} < a^n,$$

and the series converges, by comparison with the convergent geometric series.

On the other hand, if $a \geqslant 1$, then $\displaystyle a^{(\sqrt[n]{2}-1)^{-1}} > a^n,$ and the series diverges.

If $a < 0$, then $\displaystyle a^{w_n}$ is a complex number with modulus $\displaystyle |a^{w_n}| = |a|^{w_n},$ and the above argument caries through to show absolute convergence when $-1 < a < 0$. If $a < -1$ the ratio test shows that the series does not converge.

(You also can apply the ratio test in all cases.)